# Chef and Puppet Windows Support

Tags: chef-infra, puppet

Between Chef and Puppet which one has better support for Windows? They both claim to do so but there several gotcha which may not be clear early on. For instance, chef does not support things like

Git
Ifconfig
Link
Package (but gem_package - for ruby gems, does work)
SCM
Script
Subversion
..

and many cookbook's use these and I assume this above makes them useless for Windows. Not sure how mature puppet is when it comes to Windows? Have you compared the chef and puppet latest windows support?

Comment: This is a subjective question and doesn't have a single cut and dry answer. It all depends on what you're trying to do. Also, I already answered on this topic (Configuration Management for Windows): http://stackoverflow.com/a/4916139/7672

Comment: Thank you. You answer is around chef and no puppet. When you say, depends, depends on what factors of what I am trying to do? Can you elaborate specially if you have experience using both?

Comment: It absolutely depends on what you're doing. I haven't used Puppet in 3.5 years and haven't used it on Windows. I think that the Windows support in Chef is really solid, and we've seen a lot of customers be very successful with it, including ancestry.com (very large Windows app installation).

Comment: We use puppet here, but we're managing 99% linux.  The native Windows support in Puppet is more limited than that of Chef, I believe, though it is catching up fast and there are several puppet modules you can install to add things like registry control, ACL control and so on.  As previously said, it is very subjective.  It likely comes down more to which you prefer to use.

Comment: I firmly believe that Chef's support for Windows is better than Puppet's. That being said, if you're using Chef or Puppet, you've made the right decision. You may have more hurdles with one over the other depending on your use cases, but simply using a framework to manage your infrastructure is a win on all counts.